# Unable to containerize Telerik Reporting API; facing issues with libgdiplus

Tags: c#, linux, docker, asp.net-core, telerik-reporting

I'm trying to run a Telerik Reporting (version 15.2.21.1125) sample ([official docs](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/using-reports-in-applications/dot-net-core-support#containerize-telerik-reporting)) into a Debian container with no luck.

Every time the HTTP request for a report is being handled, an error occurs in *libgdiplus* and the container immediately dies with the following error code:

```
*** Error in `dotnet': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00007f4cc000e6e0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x70bfb)[0x7f518bf30bfb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x76fc6)[0x7f518bf36fc6]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7780e)[0x7f518bf3780e]
/usr/lib/libgdiplus.so(+0x1406e)[0x7f4cf005b06e]
/usr/lib/libgdiplus.so(GdipGetFontCollectionFamilyCount+0x28)[0x7f4cf005b7f8]
[0x7f5118bb9c8f]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00418000 r-xp 00000000 08:10 294519                             /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet
00618000-00619000 r--p 00018000 08:10 294519                             /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet
00619000-0061a000 rw-p 00019000 08:10 294519                             /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet
0151b000-0197e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]

...
```

I've tried running the same project with a higher version of dotnet (up to 5) and libgdiplus (up to 6) but similar problems occur.

Has anyone managed to run Telerik Reporting under Linux?

Answer (score 0):

When deploying to a Linux machine, make sure it has the library [libgdiplus](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/libgdiplus/) installed, which is the Mono implementation of the GDI+ API for non-Windows operating systems. The following code snippet performs the update and installs the necessary libraries on Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
sudo apt-get install libgdiplus
```

Please refer to this post:

[Using Telerik Reporting in Applications on Linux Platform](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/use-reports-in-net-core-apps?&_ga=2.158411321.2047658829.1643073889-1057222807.1641264258#using-telerik-reporting-in-applications-on-linux-platform)

Comment: Hi @Chaodeng, thanks for your attention but,  as stated in the question, I'm aware that the library needs to be installed and the very same commands you posted are included in the link that I've provided